# Graphics.h doesn't want to work with CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, block, bgi

so we did graphics in CodeBlocks at school and we went and downloaded WinBGIm and extracted everything. We followed tutorials from Youtube and it worked. As soon as I came home, I tried installing it and it just won't work. I put the files in right folders and changed *right* to *top* in line 302. As soon as I build the program, it says: *fatal error: graphics.h: No such file or directory*. Tried searching the forums, and all of them lead to the same solution, which is trying everything I tried already. If anyone of you experienced this, pls let me know. Thanks

Comment: Have you specified the folder containing graphics.h in the compiler search list

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder containing graphics.h in the compiler search list for the project

[image]

Comment: All project options are grayed out

Comment: Do you mean the options in the dropdown Project menu? Best guess: you are using codeblocks to run the application and the application is still running.  Fix:  Stop the application.